# IModelBinder Delay

Tags: imodelbinder

I have created controller that use an interface as the post parameter. Since the parameter an interface I use IModelBinder to translate the request.Body into IQuery object. The parsing by IModelBinder has no issue, and execution on Controller also have no issue. The only issue that I got is that there's a delay from the request.Body being parsed into IQuery object till get received on Controller body.

The IModelBinder that I use to parse the request body:

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    string _queryJson = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        _queryJson = _reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (_queryJson.IsEmpty())
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            goto done;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        goto done;
    }

    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(QueryBuilder.ParseJson(DataContext, _queryJson));
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"QUERY PARSING COMPLETE {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff")}");
    done:
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Query(IQuery query)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"QUERY ON CONTROLLER {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff")}");
        query.ThrowArgumentNullException("query", "Missing query to execute");
        if (query is ISelectQuery)
        {
            var _rows = ((ISelectQuery)query)
                .ReadAll()
                .ToArray();
            return new EntitiesResult(((ISelectQuery)query).ViewEntity, _rows.Length, _rows);
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Only select query can be executed for now");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { return new ExceptionResult(ex); }
}
```

As the code above I put Trace to track when the IQuery object finish parsed and when the Controller receive the IQuery object. I look into the output window and found that after being parsed and received on controller there's a 10+s delay.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vOqc.png)

I thought this might related to Logging, so I disable the logging on the start up:

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.None)
                 .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.None)
                 .AddFilter("NToastNotify", LogLevel.None)
                 .AddConsole();
});
```

The result still there's delay and the call to ToString method of IQuery object still being called [disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvoFD.png)

Call request example : [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKu36.png)

I didn't found the source code for ASP.Net Core ModelBindingContext or any so I didn't have clue what cause the object delay after being parsed by binder and received on controller.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. After reading the source of ParameterBinder and enable the logging into Trace mode, I found the cause which is ObjectModelValidator. The validator kicks in and validate my IQuery after my binder done parsing. This cause the delay on [ParameterBinder](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/ParameterBinder.cs)

To fix this, I use temporary solution that given on [disable validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374994/correct-way-to-disable-model-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-mvc) by Skorunka František

Now I just need to find the way to disable the validator only for my specific IModelBinder