# Disable automatic model validation ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I have a `Save` method which gets a view model passed in. In the Viewmodel I have a bunch of custom validations that happen.

```
public class DealViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    }
}

public IActionResult SaveDeal(DealViewModel dealViewModel)
{
}
```

I want to run the validation after it hits the save method as I need to get information from session update the view model and then validate.

This is how I validate:

```
 var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(dealViewModel, context, results, true);
```

But my code hits the validation method before it even its in the `SaveDeal` method in the controller.

Is there  a way to stop that and just force validate when I am ready?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [Correct way to disable model validation in ASP.Net Core 2 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374994/correct-way-to-disable-model-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-mvc)

But this might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#disable-validation

Basically, add a new class that inherits the IObjectModelValidator but does nothing on the Validate method. Also add it to the dependency injection container.