# FluentValidations .NotEmpty() validator not returning the desired error message

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

So, i am using FluentValidations to validate some request parameters on my API Controller, and all built-in validators return exactly the message i want, except for the .NotEmpty() validator.

Validator class:

```
public class UserByNameRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<UserByNameRequest>
    {
        private const string _defaultInvalidMessage = "Informed parameter {0} is invalid.";

        public UserByNameRequestValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(userRequest => userRequest.Name)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage(string.Format(_defaultInvalidMessage, nameof(UserByNameRequest.Name), string.Empty))
                .Length(3, 64)
                .WithMessage(string.Format(_defaultInvalidMessage, nameof(UserByNameRequest.Name), string.Empty));

            When(userRequest => userRequest.ExactMatch != null, () =>
            {
                RuleFor(userRequest => userRequest.ExactMatch)
                .Must(x => x.Equals(true) || x.Equals(false))
                .WithMessage(string.Format(_defaultInvalidMessage, nameof(UserByNameRequest.ExactMatch), string.Empty));
            });

            When(userRequest => userRequest.Sort != null, () =>
            {
                RuleFor(userRequest => userRequest.Sort)
                .IsInEnum()
                .WithMessage(string.Format(_defaultInvalidMessage, nameof(UserByNameRequest.Sort), string.Empty));
            });
        }
    }
```

The UserByNameRequest class:

```
public class UserByNameRequest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool? ExactMatch { get; set; }
        public SortEnum? Sort { get; set; }

    }
```

The RequestByNameErrorResponseDomain class:

```
public class RequestByNameErrorResponseDomain
    {
        public RequestByNameErrorResponseDomain()
        {
            Parameters = new UserByNameRequest();
        }

        public List<string>? ErrorMessage{ get; set; }
        public UserByNameRequest? Parameters { get; set; }
    }
```

If i send a request that triggers the .Length(3,64) validator, this is what i get on Postman:

```
{
    "errorMessage": [
        "Informed parameter Name is invalid."
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "name": "ab",
        "exactMatch": null,
        "sort": null
    }
}
```

But if i send a empty Name parameter, this is the return i get:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-e365ac223ec634f2e5bc016529c3600f-000110d0b9d4ed6d-00",
    "errors": {
        "Name": [
            "The Name field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the validation part of my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("findUsersByName")]
        public ActionResult<List<UserResponseDomain>> GetUsersByName([FromQuery] UserByNameRequest filter)
        {
            try
            {
                var validationResult = _userByNameRequestValidator.Validate(filter);

                if (!validationResult.IsValid)
                {
                    var errors = _getValidationErrors.GetErrors(validationResult);

                    _logger.LogError($"The request parameters are invalid: {errors}");

                    RequestByNameErrorResponseDomain errorResponseDomain = new();
                    {
                        errorResponseDomain.ErrorMessage = errors;
                        errorResponseDomain.Parameters.Name = filter.Name;
                        errorResponseDomain.Parameters.ExactMatch = filter.ExactMatch;
                        errorResponseDomain.Parameters.Sort = filter.Sort;
                    };

                    return BadRequest(errorResponseDomain);
                }
```

And finally this is the method used to get the errors:

```
public List<string> GetErrors(ValidationResult validationResult)
        {
            List<string> errors = validationResult.Errors.Select((ValidationFailure x) => x.ErrorMessage).Distinct().ToList();

            return errors;
        }
```

I am going crazy about it, every other validator returns the message i want just fine, except for the .NotEmpty()

Comment: Does `UserByNameRequest` have the `[Required]` attribute applied to the `Name` property? It's not showing in the class you posted, but perhaps you had a similar copy/paste error there. The message you're seeing is returned by the model validation represented in the `ModelState`.

Comment: Hahaha no copy/paste error there @madreflection, it doesn't have the [Required] attribute, but now that you mentioned it, i guess it should, since it is indeed a obrigatory parameter, is this what is causing my error?

Comment: Well, no, it probably shouldn't because that would definitely trigger the model validation that returns the message you don't want.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need, so that only FluentValidation is being used https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533736 .

Comment: That worked perfectly @madreflection, i had never heard about the existence of this [ValidateNever] attribute, thank you so much! :)