# Disable model validation for custom binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have created a custom model binder and would like to disable model validation. How to do that?

```
   public class ConverterModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            ///...creating and binding ConversionModel 
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(ConversionModel );

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

The controller action is never executed because build in model validator kicks in for my ConversionModel object. I don't want to validate it.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Convert([ModelBinder(typeof(ConverterModelBinder))] ConversionModel model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following methods to disable model validation:

Method 1: Use the [ValidateNever](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute:

```
[ValidateNever]
public class ConversionModel {
   //... properties
}
```

Method 2: Set the [ApiBehaviorOptions.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.suppressmodelstateinvalidfilter?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to `true`:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

Refer to this thread: [Correct way to disable model validation in ASP.Net Core 2 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374994/correct-way-to-disable-model-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-mvc)

Comment: Neither of these works for me. 1. The [ValidateNever] references Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and I don't want to include it in my Domain project where ConversionModel exists. 2. This is disabled globally and I need to disable it only for one model.

Comment: To disable the model validation only for one model, the `ValidateNever` attribute should be the easiest way to do that. About you can't use the ValidateNever attribute, do you mean your website contains multiple projects? And the Domain project is like a class library, it only contains the class, and other project will add the Domain project reference, so you don't want to add the MVC reference, if that is the case, in the main project, you can add a view model (with the validateNever attribute) to receive the data, then convent it to the ConversionModel.