# Manual FluentValidation without validating twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, fluentvalidation, modelstate

The recommendation for FluentValidation is to use manual validation:

On https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html you can read that the automatic approach is deprecated:

> We no longer recommend using this approach for new projects but it is still available for legacy implementations.
>
> - It is harder to debug: The ‘magic’ nature of auto-validation makes it hard to debug/troubleshoot if something goes wrong as so much is
>   done behind the scenes.

And the manual approach is recommended:

> With manual validation, you inject the validator into your controller
> (or api endpoint), invoke the validator and act upon the result. This
> is the most straightforward approach and also the easiest to see
> what’s happening.

I totally agree that this way is cleaner and easier to understand.

But what about the built in model validation that happens before the manual validation with FluentValidation? If I implement a very complex validator with FluentValidation, it might happen that the built in validator already adds validation errors to the model state and the custom validator won't be triggered. The result is an incomplete validation of the model. But I prefer to completely validate the model, and prevent to return a different set of messages each time.

How can I prevent double validation like this? Should the built in validator be deactivated or is there another way to only use the FluentValidation validator except for the automatic approach?

Comment: what you mean by ``The new recommendation for FluentValidation``? Where or who recommends it?

Comment: I updated my question. Basically FluentValidation team recommends it.

Comment: Your comment to Aleksei's answer reveals what I think is a misconception: There is a difference between _validation_ and _failed deserialization_. If your model contains a non-nullable property and your deserializer is setup so it doesn't allow (and handle) missing properties, then it will throw / fail. You _can_ mitigate that by either designing your model to be forgiving and/or configuring your deserializer to be forgiving. Then you'll get a model instance that you _can_ validate in the first place.

Comment: ^^ That said: Having both FV-Auto and FV-Manual shoud be trivial to resolve and I now understand isn't the question, right?

Comment: Add one string? and one string property to the model, string? is decorated with [Required] attribute, send both empty in a request => both error messages will be added to the output, and not only "the failed deserialization". It's obviously not a deserialization issue, but an implicit validator applied to the non-nullable type. It's not  a missconception to do all validation in a single point of the request.  You don't want the user to get validation messages in batches.

Answer (score 0):

FluentValidation has built-in extension `.AddToModelState()`, so it's possible to add validation errors from fluent validator to errors from asp.net core validation. Example from their docs:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Person person) 
{
  ValidationResult result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(person);

  if (!result.IsValid) 
  {
    // Copy the validation results into ModelState.
    // ASP.NET uses the ModelState collection to populate 
    // error messages in the View.
    result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
    // re-render the view when validation failed.
    return View("Create", person);
  }

  _repository.Save(person); //Save the person to the database, or some other logic

  TempData["notice"] = "Person successfully created";
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Source: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Also you could "turn off" asp.net core validation, if you want: [Correct way to disable model validation in ASP.Net Core 2 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374994/correct-way-to-disable-model-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-mvc)

Comment: If the Person.FirstName property is defined as nonnullable string, and you pass no FirstName in the API request JSON, then ValidateAsync and your custom validator will never be executed. The built in validation will already return the errors. And that exactly is the issue I try to resolve.

Comment: @Ben5 That's a different level of error, though. If the model requires the property to be _present_ and it isn't, then it's a Bad Request, period. You can design the model to not _technically_ require the property being present (or the deserializer) and _then_ add validation to ensure it has a value.

Comment: @Fildor Not really, as I explained in the comment of the question.

Comment: @Aleksei Petrov Your addition with turning off model validation of asp.net core solves the issue, but it was kind of already mentioned in the question. Still currently this seems the only way how to prevent double validation. An alternative would be to use a third party library for auto-validation which will replace the built in validator, with the disadvantage of using "auto-magic".