# ASPNET returning BadRequest when non-nullable API model specifies a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation, model-validation

Just wondering if there is a way for the ASP.NET Web API to not automatically return a bad request response when attempting to call a controller action that has a model with a non-nullable property that is set to null.

Take the following model:

```
public record TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

We are using FluentValidation and have specified a validator that ensures the property Name is not empty (which includes a null test, and has been verified with other tests against just the validator), with an error code:

```
RuleFor(model => model.Name)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithErrorCode(ErrorConstants.NameCannotBeEmpty);
```

We are then calling the validator manually in the controller as is the recommended approach:

```
var result = await _postValidator.ValidateAsync(request);
if (!result.IsValid)
{
    return GetValidationErrorResponse(result);
}
```

We then return a custom response object using `GetValidationErrorResponse` which contains the error code of the error. This will help us to display multi-lingual error messages, where we can lookup the error based on an error code.

We then have a set of tests we run, where we want to explicitly test for either `"Name": ""` or `"Name": null`.

When we call the test with `"Name": ""` the controller POST action is called, and the manual test of the fluent validator is called, which results in the BadRequest response containing the correct error code.

When we call the test `"Name": null` the controller POST action is not called, and it just returns the standard ASPNET BadRequest object, which states the name of the field but as it's not hitting the fluent validation check, and therefore not adding the error code into the response to be picked up by the front end.

I understand the nature of the non-nullable field would indicate that this should never be null, however that a dotnet centric thing, and I don't want to have to make the field nullable, when it shouldn't be.

But I want to be able to explicitly verify that a client that incorrectly passes a null value (which would be a valid JSON object) is still returned the appropriate error code as we've designed.

Is there a way to disable this automatic model validation within asp.net and explicitly rely only on our calls to the fluent validation methods?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to disable model validation in ASP.Net Core 2 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374994/correct-way-to-disable-model-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-mvc)

Comment: I notice that you are tagging [tag:asp.net], AFAIK ASP.NET Web API doesn't automatically validation unless you are calling `ModelState.IsValid` (or you implement it in an `ActionFilter`.

Comment: According to that post, it looks like it does, as `services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelValidatorProviders` shows 18 providers. Thinking about this more, I don't know that I want to clear all those providers. For example, if the model specifies a Guid type, I don't want to manually validate that the field is a Guid, but I'd like for it to ignore/pass-through null values I guess.